# How can I set this parameter in JavaScript getusermedia?

Tags: javascript, audio, getusermedia

I want to record audio in JavaScript at a 16khz sampling rate in real-time. I have the following code:

```
navigator.getUserMedia(
    {
        "audio": {
            "mandatory": {
                "googEchoCancellation": "false",
                "googAutoGainControl": "false",
                "googNoiseSuppression": "false",
                "googHighpassFilter": "false"
            },
            "optional": {
                "sampleRate": 16000 
            }
        },
    }, gotStream, function(e) {
        console.log(e);
    });
```

But this throws the error:

> index.html:1026 Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute
>   'webkitGetUserMedia' on 'Navigator': The value provided is neither an
>   array, nor does it have indexed properties.

How can I record audio at 16khz in JavaScript in real-time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Several problems:

1. `optional` (now `advanced`) takes an array, e.g. `optional: [{ sampleRate: 16000 }]`
2. This constraints syntax is outdated and only works in Chrome.
3. `sampleRate` is not yet implemented in any browser AFAIK.

So it won't work, at least not yet. In the future, use [spec syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia#Parameters):

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
  audio: {
    echoCancellation: {exact: false},
    sampleRate: 16000,
  }
})
.then(gotStream)
.catch(e => console.log(e));
```

Comment: Update on this. You can now use these MediatrackConstraints: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaTrackConstraints